# Is it possible to decompose a method that takes an implicit block?

Tags: ruby

My end use is in rails, where I am assigning an object that implements `each` to the `response.body` of an action.

The each method is quite long and I would like to decompose it. But because of the performance difference between explicit & implicit blocks, I would like to keep the block implicit.

How do I have the decomposed methods yield to the original block?

Comment: I met the same problem a while ago. Your solution will work _until_ you want to decompose `submethod1` further and to **repass the block** to the nested method. I have written a [short blog post](http://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2013/03/03/ruby-shorthand-to-yield-within-blocks/) about how to use the not wide-known feature of `Proc.new` here, you might want to have a look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I realized how to do this right after posting my question. The answer is to call the sub-methods with a block with a parameter and yield the parameter:

```
def each
  submethod1 {|out| yield out}
  submethod2 {|out| yield out}
  yield "whatever"
end

def submethod1
  yield "submethod1"
end

def submethod2
  yield "submethod2"
end
```